# Embedding a Google Group - nothing is displayed when not logged into Google

Tags: iframe, google-groups, google-groups-api

I'm trying to embed a Google Groups forum into a page using the supplied embed code for the group. It works fine when I'm logged into Google, but if I'm not, the embed code (that creates an iframe) throws the following error (in Chrome):

> Refused to display document because display forbidden by
>   X-Frame-Options

The result is that the iframe doesn't display anything. Is there a workaround for this? My guess is that the problem is on Google's end. The page is here (if you can see the forum, make sure you are not logged into Google):

[www.jqcoolgallery.com/support.html](http://www.jqcoolgallery.com/support.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me in Chrome Incognito mode (no user signed in). I see the empty group.

Sorry, just saw you're on Chrome also. Have you tried it in a new incognito session?

Comment: Thank you for checking... seems to be working now. There must have been an issue with this feature when I made this post. I just tried it in an incognito window and it's working for me as well.

Comment: I get this error -

Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/webdriver': 'ALLOW-FROM https://groups.google.com' is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored.